# Tomcat The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, struts2, web-deployment, tomcat8

I checked this Error on google. But did not find correct solution.

For your Information, I'm using struts2, Tomcat version is 'Tomcat-8.5.30', OS is Ubuntu.

web.xml :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and project contains index.jsp at proper location i.e WebContent/index.jsp

Still it is showing above error. Please provide solution.

I tried commenting following code then it is working. But I need this lines of code to work my application.

```
<!-- 
        <action name="UploadLeavesData">
             <interceptor-ref name="authStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="error">view/common/error.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">view/employees/uploadEmpLeavesFileFromGreytHr.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="importLeaves" class="com.zCon.controller.LeaveFileUploadAction" method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">20971520</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">  
                    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/octet-stream
                </param>  
            </interceptor-ref>  
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="input">view/employees/uploadEmpLeavesFileFromGreytHr.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="redirect">UploadLeavesData</result>
        </action>
 -->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your web app exists in **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat XX\webapps** as somehow Tomcat folder exists both here and in **C:\tomcat-XXXX** for my case.

After moving my application inside there it works. It seems the real directory it is pointing is that one.